# java sorting issue

Tags: java, sorting

I have a arraylist of a POJO and the data in it is of the form

```
id    time
2     467
3     403
4     602
3     529
5     398
```

The requirement is that first I need to sort the data by time and then after that the same IDs should be one after the other i.e

```
id     time
5      398
3      403
3      529
2      467
4      602.
```

Initially to sort by time , I'm using the following logic

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Asset>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Asset o1, Asset o2) {

                        if (o1.getTime() > o2.getTime())

                            return -1;

                        else if (o1.getTime() < o2.getTime())

                            return 1;

                        else

                            return 0;

                    }

                });
```

Could some one help me in clubbing by IDs in the next stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the data according to the example you gave, you probably need two passes over the list. (How else would you determine whether or not `3 504` should come before or after `5 315`?)

1. Sort according to time.
2. Sort the list according to the first index of each id.

Here's some sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Asset {
    public int id;
    public int time;

    public Asset(int id, int time) {
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + "  " + time;
    }
}


class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Asset> assets = new ArrayList<Asset>();
        assets.add(new Asset(2, 467));
        assets.add(new Asset(3, 403));
        assets.add(new Asset(4, 602));
        assets.add(new Asset(3, 529));
        assets.add(new Asset(5, 398));

        // Sort according to time.
        Collections.sort(assets, new Comparator<Asset>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Asset o1, Asset o2) {
                return new Integer(o1.time).compareTo(o2.time);
            }
        });

        // Remember the original indexes of each asset.
        final List<Asset> assetsCopy = new ArrayList<Asset>(assets);

        // Sort the collection based on the index of the first asset
        // with the same id
        Collections.sort(assets, new Comparator<Asset>() {

            private int firstIndexOf(int id) {
                for (int i = 0; i < assetsCopy.size(); i++)
                    if (assetsCopy.get(i).id == id)
                        return i;
                return -1;
            }

            @Override
            public int compare(Asset o1, Asset o2) {
                return new Integer(firstIndexOf(o1.id))
                        .compareTo(firstIndexOf(o2.id));
            }
        });


        for (Asset a : assets)
            System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5  398
3  403
3  529
2  467
4  602
```

Comment: Not exactly, I want the sorting by time intially and then the items with same ID should appear together

Comment: so you want to sort by time and group by id?

Comment: YEs I want to sort by time and group by id

Comment: An even more condensed way is to not create new Long/Integer objects, and just use the static methods Double.compare(n1,n2).

Comment: @aioobe Could you come in detail as I couldnt get you

Comment: @aioobe U r the mighty champion:)

Answer (score 0):

below code is an example. The idea is to check if the times are equal, if they are sort on id, else sort on time.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Asset>() {
     @Override
     public int compare(Asset o1, Asset o2) {
         if(o1.getTime() != 02.getTime()) {
             if (o1.getTime() > o2.getTime())
                 return -1;
             else
                 return 1;
         } else {
             return new Integer(o1.getId()).compareTo(o2.getId());
         }
     });
```

Comment: `o1.getId() - o2.getId()` is a bad idea due to overflows.

Comment: overflows ? check the OP's post; the chance on overflows looks pretty small to me.

Comment: The code is still buggy. Much better to fall back on `Integer.compareTo` for instance.

Comment: I guess you need java 7 for that.

Comment: aioobe was so friendly to edit my post; it should work now, if not, debugging it will help.

Comment: @Tom, he's after something different after all ;-)

Comment: dude, really, I never post trivial code like that again; they'll have to do it with something like: if(time equal)(sort on id)else(sort on time)...I just trying to help you know and that on a monday morning.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Collections.sort(...)` is guaranteed to be a *stable sorting algorithm* you can simply go and first sort by time and then sort by id.

*Stable sorting* guarantees that equal elements remain in the same order as before.

For your example:

1. sort by time
2. sort by id

After first step all your times are sorted. After the second step your collection is sorted by id - and for equal ids they remain in the same order since the sorting is stable.

So for same ids they are still sorted by time in the second place.
You can drive this up to as many sortings as you like without holding any state of previous sortings. And that's only because you're using stable sorting.

**Output**

```
2  467
3  403
3  529
4  602
5  398
```

Comment: You have to be careful though, because as you can see in the example, the result is not actually sorted by id.

Comment: Well, as far as I can see the OP just want them grouped by ID after sorting by time. This can be archieved by sorting by id. Cannot see any restriction about ID order in OP's post. So I assume it is ok to have them ordered as well. But maybe I misunderstood something ...

Comment: Added the output of this solution to clarify the differences.